# Pip and/or installing the .pyd of library to site-packages leads "import" of library to DLL load faliure

Tags: python, opencv, dll, pip

I attempted to install Opencv for python two ways, 
A) Downloading the opencv zip, then copying cv2.pyd to /Python36/lib/site-packages.

B) undoing that, and using "pip install opencv-python"

/lib/site-packages is definitly the place where python is loading my modules, as tensorflow and numpy are there, but any attempt to "import cv2" leads to "ImportError: DLL Load Failed: The specified module could not be found"

I am at a loss, any help appreciated. And yes i have tried reinstalling VC redist 2015

Comment: Reinstall python maybe? You would lose all of your site-packages though that you installed.

Comment: many sources online seem to indicate that maybe downgrading to 2.7 is the only option, is it possible to run opencv on python 3.6? Some claim so but the'res so much dichotomous info about this issue.

Comment: If i can't are there any lib's on the level (of both capability and documentation & tutorials) as opencv?

Answer (score 0):

Use the zip, extract it, and run `sudo python3 setup.py install` if you are on Mac or Linux. If on Windows, open cmd or Powershell in Admin mode and then run `py -3.6 setup.py install`, after `cd`ing to the path of the zip. If on Linux, you also have to run `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`. Maybe on Mac you have to use Homebrew, but I am not sure.

Comment: Seems like OP is on Windows given (s)he's talking about DLLs and VC